# Sort in cakephp other model

Tags: php, cakephp

I have multiple tables associated with each other:

1. Messages
2. Message details

Message details has the fields `id`, `Message_id`, `created_date`  and `message`.

I want to sort messages on the message details `created_date`.

How can I do that?

```
$messages = $this->Message->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array('Message.status'=> 'progress')
                ));
// What do I do now to sort it on message_details created time?

class  MessageDetail extends AppModel {
  //public $hasMany=array('MessageDetail');
  //$belongsTo = array('Message');

   public $belongsTo = array(

    'Message' => array(
        'className'    => 'Message',
        'foreignKey'   => 'message_id'
    )       

     );
}

class  Message extends AppModel {
  public $hasMany=array('MessageDetail');
}
```

Comment: HI, You need to take data from only message table right ?

Comment: no from both tables im using association for this and it give me all data

Comment: What is the model class of Message details table ?

Comment: @KarthikKeyan in cakephp, Model names are singular, so `message_details` would be `MessageDetail`

Comment: yes i know bro association working perfect there is no issue in it. now question is that how i can sort it on create_date field MessageDetail

Answer (score 0):

You can simple pass order, and mention which field to sort, see below:

```
$messages = $this->Message->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Message.status'=> 'progress'),
    'ORDER' => 'MessageDetail.created_date ASC'

));
```

**UPDATE**

You Message.php Model will look like:

```
class Message extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MessageDetail' => array(
            'className' => 'MessageDetail',
            'foreignKey' => 'message_id',
            'order' => 'MessageDetail.created_date DESC'
        ),  
    );

}
```

and MessageDetail.php Model will be:

```
class MessageDetail extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Message' => array(
            'className' => 'Message',
            'foreignKey' => 'message_id'
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: hope you've replaced `MessageDetail.created_time`  with your's `MessageDetail.created_date`, if it still not works, share your association code as well!

Comment: Okay, can you share you association code between `Message` and `MessageDetail` as well ?

Comment: class  Message extends AppModel {
  public $hasMany=array('MessageDetail');
}

Comment: edit your question, and add your code , like you added that query

Comment: class  MessageDetail extends AppModel {  
   public $belongsTo = array(
    'Message' => array(
        'className'    => 'Message',
        'foreignKey'   => 'message_id'
    )       

     );
}

Comment: no bro still now working thanks for reply. i tried with this question

Comment: ah Okay, could you please try again by adding `'order' => 'MessageDetail.created_date DESC'` order in `$hasMany` association .. also updated answer.

Ref [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#relationship-types)

Answer (score 0):

Can You pls try this code,You need Descending order put DESC instead of ASC

```
           $messages = $this->Message->find('all', array(
           'conditions' => array('Message.status'=> 'progress'),
           'order' => array('MessageDetails.created_date ASC')
            ));
```

Comment: not bro it's not working it's diffrent model MessageDetail.created_date